# NavigationView for macOS 10.15

Tags: swiftui, macos-catalina, navigationview

I find some tutorials online for `NavigationView`, one example is [here](https://dev.to/tprezioso/how-to-make-a-sidebar-menu-in-swiftui-ejl).
However, most of examples are for macOS 11, but I want to run on macOS 10.15 or lower. Here is an example code:

```
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        List {
            Label("Books", systemImage: "book.closed")
            Label("Tutorials", systemImage: "list.bullet.rectangle")
            Label("Video Tutorials", systemImage: "tv")
            Label("Contacts", systemImage: "mail.stack")
            Label("Search", systemImage: "magnifyingglass")
        }
                .listStyle(SidebarListStyle())
                .navigationTitle("Code")
    }
```

However, this code error at `Label`. How can I fix this for running on macOS 10.15

Thanks

Comment: Don't use `Label`, it is not available in macOS 10.15, as well as SF symbols as system images.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have any recommendation? It's frustrated that all results are for the newer version only :(

Comment: Well... I would like to have SwiftUI worked on iOS 12 ... but this sounds strange, right? )))

Comment: Actually I want to write MacOS application for 10.15, at least right now because my machine cannot upgrade to 10.16 because of software compatibility. And I don't want that, too.

Comment: You can use AppKit + SwiftUI 1.0

Comment: Thanks for the keyword. I don't know this is called SwiftUI 1.0.

Comment: MacOS 10.11?  That's several years old.  How do you run SwiftUI under MacOS 10.11?

Comment: I assume you mean macOS 11 (Big Sur)? If so, and you get the chance, it would be helpful for you to edit your question to clarify this (as 10.11 refers to El Capitan, which is now 5 years old)

Comment: Thanks. My apologies for this confusion. I mean macOS 11.